# Injecting the database context in an MVC Core project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, repository

lets say I have a small MVC Core application where I want to switch between two database engines without much hassle  (as an example I have Entity Framework Core and MongoDB).

In my appsettings.json, I have the following nodes:

```
{
  "UseMongo": false,
  "MongoDB": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://127.0.0.1",
    "DatabaseName": "CoreDB",
    "IsSSL": true
  },
  "EntityDB": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://127.0.0.1",
    "DatabaseName": "CoreDB"
  }
}
```

Then in my Startup.cs, I have the following code:

```
if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseMongo"))
{
    MongoDbContext.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:ConnectionString").Value;
    MongoDbContext.DatabaseName = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB:DatabaseName").Value; 
    //Somehow inject context into application so it is available globally               
}
else
{
    EfDbContext.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("EntityDB:ConnectionString").Value;
    EfDbContext.DatabaseName = Configuration.GetSection("EntityDB:DatabaseName").Value;
    //Somehow inject context into application so it is available globally
}
```

I then declare an interface from which two repository classes derive:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
   void GetData();
}

public class EfRepository : IRepository
{
   public void GetData()
   {
      //DB logic
   }
}

public class MongoRepository : IRepository
{
   public void GetData()
   {
      //DB logic
   }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to use either repository class depending on the "UseMongo" switch in my appsettings.json. I have looked a little into dependency injection but I haven't found a solution. I want to be able to do this in my Controllers:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public ValuesController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository= repository;
    }
}
```

Is something like this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseMongo"))
{
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository),typeof(MongoRepository))
}
else
{
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository),typeof(EfRepository))
}
```

Comment: Just one question: Is this a good practice? Because all the examples I read where DbContext is injected use services.AddDbContext for injecting a context.

Comment: How you're creating instance of DbContext? Are you creating it inside the repository or you're injecting it using DI? If you're using DI you can add AddDbContext method.

Comment: I haven't implemented that part yet but I plan to instantiate it inside my repository class so I guess I would be fine without using AddDbContext if I understand it correctly.

Comment: If you are initializing DB context inside Repository, you can't unit test them.